# changing screen size

Tags: java, screen-resolution, screen-size

I am developing an application for MS Windows in Java. What I want to do and don't know how is this:
Let's say the user's screen resolution is set to 1000x1000, and my app size is 400x100. Now I want to change the user's screen size to 1000x900 and put my app in this 100px high bar. When a user will open i.e. a internet browser and maximize it, the browser will maximize like 1000x900 is the real screen resolution, so my app window can always be seen by the user. Hope sb knows if it's possible in Java.

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called an [*Application Desktop Toolbar*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx) and no, it's not possible from plain Java. You will need to resort to native code for this.